# UNION Query on Multiple Tables with New Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wanna say that this forum has been really helping me a lot in my current work.

I am in need of another help in writing an sql query for our ms access database. The idea is to make a union query for all the tables (January to December) to get the unique ID numbers and get their "Item" values per month as a column in the output table.

An example could be seen below. If the ID cannot be found in the table, the value will be returned null.

This seemed easy to do in excel but we would like to do it in our backend. I've only gotten as far as writing down the UNION query for all the tables but that's how far I got.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Table 1: January

```
 |    ID    |   Item    |
 |    1     |   Apple   |
 |    2     |   Salad   |
 |    3     |   Grapes  |
```

Table 2: February

```
 |    ID    |   Item    |
 |    1     |   Apple   |
 |    2     |   Grapes  |
 |    4     |   Grapes  |
```

Output Table:

```
 |    ID    |   January   |   February   |
 |    1     |    Apple    |   Apple      |
 |    2     |    Salad    |   Grapes     |
 |    3     |    Grapes   |   NULL       |
 |    4     |    NULL     |   Grapes     |
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select id, max(January) as January, max(February) as February
from (select id, item as January, NULL as February from January
      union all
      select id, NULL, item from February
     ) jf
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If id exist only once per table why not use Inner Join instead? It will automatically null out the column if it does not exist on the other table but exist on the first one

```
SELECT id, Jan.Item,Feb.Item 
FROM January Jan
INNER JOIN February Feb
on Jan.id=Feb.id
```